# asp.net core 2 routing with empty parameters

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on and MVC core2 project that has to replace an old VB code. My problem is that all the links from the old project should work in the new one. I have a pattern as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Search",
    template : "t/q={keyword}&c={city}&z={zip}&p={page}&dst={district}&sUrl={streetUrl}&cUrl={cityUrl}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index"});
```

This only works if I have all the parameters are filled. Is there any way I could make it work without filling all the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I figured out how to implement this. I removed the querystring part from the template. So basically, the template will be

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Search",
                template : "t/",
                defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index"});
```

and after this, the Index Action will be

```
public IActionResult CompanySearch([FromQuery(Name = "q")] string keyword, [FromQuery(Name = "c")] string city, [FromQuery(Name = "z")] string zip, [FromQuery(Name = "p")] int page, [FromQuery(Name = "dist")] string district, [FromQuery(Name = "sUrl")] string streetUrl, [FromQuery(Name = "cUrl")] string cityUrl)
{
    //other stuffs
    return View();
}
```